# Django-Channels 2 Apache CentOS 7 deploy

Tags: django, apache, websocket, django-channels, daphne

I can't make Apache serve websockets through Daphne.

The **requirements.txt**
`Django==2.0.7
channels==2.1.3
asgiref==2.3.2
redis==2.10.6`
**settings.py**

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default":{
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("localhost"), 6379],
        },
        "ROUTING": "myapp.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}

ASGI_APPLICATION = "myapp.routing.application"
USE_WEBSOCKETS = True
```

**routing.py**

```
#..imports  

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r"", MyConsumer),
]

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                websocket_urlpatterns
            )
        )
    )
})
```

**asgi.py**

```
#.. imports

os.environment.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
django.setup()
application = get_default_application()
```

**MyConsumer.py**

```
#..imports

class MyConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def websocket_connect(self, event):
        Logger.log("Connected " + json.dumps(event))
        self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })

    def websocket_receive(self, event):
        Logger.log("Receive " + json.dumps(event))

    def websocket_disconnect(self, event):
        Logger.log("Disconnected " + json.dumps(event))
```

**httpd.conf**

```
#...
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:9001%{REQUEST_URI} [P, QSA, L]
```

**supervisord.conf**

```
;...    
[fcgi-program:asgi]
socket=tcp://127.0.0.1:9001
command=/var/www/venv/bin/daphne -u /run/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --fd 0 --access-log - --proxy-headers myapp.asgi.application
numprocs=2
process_name=asgi%(process_num)d
directory=/var/www/venv/myapp/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/asgi.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

In javascript, I just try to connect:

```
var location = window.location
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + location.host + ':9001' + location.pathname)
socket.onopen = function(e){
    console.log('open', e)
}
socket.onerror = function(e){
    console.log('error', e)
}
socket.onclose = function(e){
    console.log('close', e)
}
```

Each time the page is accessed it gives `WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:9001/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` after a while and prints the error and close messages in console.
I followed the example setup provided at [readthedocs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html#example-setups) and used an nginx instance, but it gives the same error.
It seems that the message is not received by the backend, so I suppose there must be something in the setup, namely with the messaging queue or redis server. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah i sped quite a bit troubleshooting a setup simmilar to yours. I am currently running channels2, daphne,redis and apache together on a centos 7.5 server. Finally working perfectly.

I find troubleshooting a bit easier using AsyncConsumer, gives a bit more control.
Try doing :

```
from channels.consumer import SyncConsumer, AsyncConsumer
class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        # when the socket connects
        print(event)
        await self.send({
            "type": "websocket.accept"
        })
```

then you can see the data comming in, if any.

And for apache, like you, I use the rewrite engine. (in the vhost file)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:9001%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
```

Hope you figure it out !
/R

Comment: yeap, I changed it to use SyncConsumer, seems to be working, but now there's another problem - when using this configuration with apache it has problems with utf8 filenames (when use daphne directly - no issues with unicode also when use the nginx to proxy websocket traffic,  only with apache - for some reason it uses the ascii charset although I set it to utf8)